# How to create an alternative name for Azure Website?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Lets assume we have a domain name for our Azure website called "myOrders.com" which is hosted on a domain service where we have configured a CName record to point to our Azure Website ie:

```
myorders.com -> myorders-app1.azurewebsites.com
```

We recently had this domain service fail, so nobody could access our site. We were trying to work out the best workaround while the domain service returned to service which it now has. I did not feel comfortable handing out "myorders-app1.azurewebsites.com" to our customers either. My only thought on this was to register another domain with another domain service ie

```
myorders-app.com -> myorders-app1.azurewebsites.com
```

Is this this the right approach to circumventing domain service failures?

My other idea was to rename our azurewebsite instance to something more friendly, but I cannot see how this can be done, and then it still would have "azurewebsites.com" as the domain.

I would appreciate an advice on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't remove the default *.azurewebsites.net addres for an Azure Web App instance.
2. You can add multiple CNAME aliases to an Azure Web App as long as you configure them to be accepted CNAMES in the Azure Management Portal for the Web App instance. Simply repeat the process you used for the first CNAME you added.

Your domain service failure isn't really an Azure-related issue, however, you could consider delegating your DNS to the new [Azure DNS service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns/) (in preview) which will provide you with a highly available DNS service (you could also consider [AWS Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) for the same thing).

Comment: Simon, thank you for this. Yes I appreciate it is not Azure related per se, but a DNS issue. It seems that you are recommending to have more than one domain name pointing to the Azure instance in case one domain service fails. Am I correct?

Comment: Also I am interested in the CloudFlare security layer, so putting this between the domain service and the Azure app is attractive. Not sure how this would work with the Azure DNS offering. Also if the Azure app is down, there is no current way in Azure to put up a professional "app not available page", where this could be done in CloudFlare as I understand it.

Comment: You would need to run multiple Web App instances (in different Azure Regions) and then put Azure Traffic Manager over the top with a Failover policy in place.